# Using ArcObjects Sample for Custom vertex editing commands?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arcgis-engine, vertices, standard-license-level

I downloaded this sample :
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Custom_vertex_editing_commands/0001000002pz000000/

it's a Dynamic Link Library. 
using Visual studio i generated the dll file from this project :

- the dll file is **VertexCommands_VB.dll**.

i imported the DLL to my application and it's works fine **BUT When i want to execute the application in other computer* it didn't work**

How do I generate the Dll on this computer* to work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this solution and it's works :

1. right click in the dll file and click register 
   [image]
2. select desktop and click register

[image]

or use :

http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37639